# Get range of hours by time now

Tags: php, datetime, time, date-format, hour

I need to get the range of hour by current time, its means:

If current time is 18:25 i need to make a array (18:00,19:00).

I try to:

```
$hourFromAut = Date('H'); // Time current
$hourTo += 1;
$hourRange = array($hourFromAut,$hourTo)
```

But this get out of the range.

Comment: Yes, sorry, i don't write ";" in the last line code, but this is not a problem. With my code i dont have a valid range. If current time is 18:25 i need to make a array (18:00,19:00). and my code return array(18:25,19:25). Thanks.

Comment: better work with [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) than with strings. That way you can easily set the minutes to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has answered this yet.

As others have mentioned in the comments, this is easier using `DateTime()` which offers you more control over dates and times.

```
$currentHour = (new DateTime())->format('H:00');
$nextHour    = (new DateTime('+1 hour'))->format('H:00');
$hourRange   = [$currentHour, $nextHour];
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/veQQ5)

There's many way to go about this, especially using `DateTime()` but this should get you started.

Comment: Hi @Alfinoide. If this, or any answer, has solved your question please consider [accepting it](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer-er and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would [getdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Vancouver'); // if server is not correct time - change to your timezone of course
$dt = getdate(); $hour = $dt['hours']; $hourRange = [$hour.':00', ($hour+1).':00'];
?>
```

Comment: You should put each statement on a separate line for readability. Your solution [also doesn't work](https://3v4l.org/tS4Im)

Comment: I indent my code, when using functions. I just don't like scrolling through all those lines of code. Your test server is in a different timezone.

Comment: It wasn't the hours that were wrong. You forgot the minutes.

Comment: Minutes are there now. It's a good practice to include `date_default_timezone_set()` in case you ever transport your code to a Sever in a different timezone.